# Create a setter function by using a smart pointer Attribute?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I have a smart pointer attribute and I want to create a setter function to it.

i know there are a method to do it as a following:

```
void setB(std::shared_ptr<B> b)
{
    //b_ptr is a shared_ptr
    b_ptr = b;
}
```

how do i create a setter as a following

```
void setB(B * b)
{
   // i want to assign b to b_ptr which b_ptr is a shared_ptr
}
```

Comment: Do you want `b_ptr` to share ownership with whatever currently owns `b`? Or do you want to transfer ownership to `b_ptr`?

Comment: to transfer the ownership @Galik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to transfer *ownership* of (the responsibility to delete) the pointer in your function you can do this:

```
void setB(B* b)
{
    b_ptr = std::shared_ptr<B>(b);
}
```